# Eclipse - Can not reach market place

Tags: java, eclipse, marketplace

I am trying to install glassfish on my Eclipse but I have an issue each time I try to access it :
[image]

Resource not found: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.8.2.v20200210-1402&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=fr_FR&java.version=1.8.0_231&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.15.0.I20200305-0155&runtime.version=3.17.100.v20200203-0917&platform.version=4.15.0.v20200305-0155
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.8.2.v20200210-1402&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=fr_FR&java.version=1.8.0_231&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.15.0.I20200305-0155&runtime.version=3.17.100.v20200203-0917&platform.version=4.15.0.v20200305-0155

I can reach web page from inside eclipse web browser and I can reach the market place with my browser I guess it is coming from eclipse but I don't know how to solve it.

I tried to change the Network Connections settings from Native to Manual but no luck so far.

If anyone as an idea ?

Here is the stack trace :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=1.8.0_231
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core
Error
Tue Jun 02 10:54:16 CEST 2020
Failed to stream using org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport@27a4a153 - falling back to org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$$Lambda$811/602501626@46a0adaa: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultMarketplaceService.news(DefaultMarketplaceService.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultMarketplaceService.news(DefaultMarketplaceService.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.CachingMarketplaceService.news(CachingMarketplaceService.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.performNewsDiscovery(MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceCatalog.performNewsDiscovery(MarketplaceCatalog.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceWizard.lambda$3(MarketplaceWizard.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.execute(HttpClientTransport.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.RequestTemplate.executeImpl(RequestTemplate.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.RequestTemplate.execute(RequestTemplate.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:104)
    ... 11 more
Contains: Connection failed

This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.execute(HttpClientTransport.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.RequestTemplate.executeImpl(RequestTemplate.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.RequestTemplate.execute(RequestTemplate.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultMarketplaceService.news(DefaultMarketplaceService.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultMarketplaceService.news(DefaultMarketplaceService.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.CachingMarketplaceService.news(CachingMarketplaceService.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.performNewsDiscovery(MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceCatalog.performNewsDiscovery(MarketplaceCatalog.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceWizard.lambda$3(MarketplaceWizard.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

I have the same issue from Help->Marketplace and from the welcome menu.

Thx

UPDATE : I manage to make it work again by deleting all the . folder (.me2, .plguings ...)

Comment: Did you try updating eclipse? When I had faced this issue an update resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried to installed the latest eclipse version and also to update eclipse but doesn't change a thing. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall market place but did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing, it can be an effect if using JDK instead of JRE on the installation. That Update/Marketplace will not work then.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi Everyone,**

**This is not a JDK issue, and not required to install a new eclipse.**

**The root cause is the internet not connecting inside the eclipse.**

Here are the steps for modifying the network inside eclipse:

1. **In eclipse - GoTo --> Preferences --> Network Connections**
2. **Inside "Network Connections" -->  select ActiveProvider = manual**
3. **Click on "Apply & Close".**
4. **Restart eclipse**.

you will get access to Marketplace.

eclipse Preferences screenshot for reference :
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flljz.png**

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : I manage to make it work again by deleting all the . folder (.me2, .plguings ...)